# JQuery three key events with ajax + semantic ui

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

hope someone can help me here: I´m developing a time recording web service. One key event shall start/stop a new/running timer. The other one is for deleting a record and closing the semantic ui modal. The problem is that i have to unbind the key events for start/stop bcs if not the ajax call is fired multiple times. Because that unbind i cant get the two (or three) events working more than one time each. I cant figure out an other  option... Im relativly new in jquery, i´ve tried it with unbind() and one()

For better example here my code snippets (first the start/stop key event) after that the semantic modal with deleting event.

```
//start new record by key(start numpad +, stop numpad - )

$(document).unbind('keydown', function(e){
    if($('button#saveButton').is(':hidden')){
        if (e.keyCode == 107) { // Numpad +
            var oRow = $('#buttonStartNew').parents('.recordRow');
            startRecord(oRow);
            return false;
        }else if(e.keyCode == 109){ // Numpad -
            var oRow = $('button.red').parents('tbody.recordRow');
            startRecord(oRow);
            return false;
        }
    }
});

//delete time record + popup

$('.removeButton').click(function(){
    var sRecordID = $(this).parents('.recordRow').find('.recordID').val();
    var clickedElement = $(this);

    if($('#modalAcceptButton').not(':hidden')){
        $(document).unbind('keydown', function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13) { // Enter
                deleteRecord(sRecordID, clickedElement)
                $('#myModal').modal('hide')
            }
        });
    }

    if($('button#saveButton').is(':hidden')){
        $('#myModal').modal({
            onDeny: function(){
                $(this).modal('hide');
            },
            onApprove: function(){
                deleteRecord(sRecordID, clickedElement);
            }
        }).modal('show')
    }else{
        clickedElement.parents('.recordRow').remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: From reading the code, should `$(document).unbind` be `$(document).bind` to accomplish your purposes? See [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) and [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Comment: With bind() the ajax call is still fired multiple times. Also the key events just work one time

Comment: Don't use `bind()` and `unbind()` in the latest versions of jQuery. These functions are depreciated. use `on()` and `off()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event listeners that fire multiple times typically happen when the binding is done more than once. This can happen if for example you are using ajax to fetch another page that also uses a similar bind command. As a result, these event listeners stack which leads to multiple executions.

In that case, instead of trying to fix this by unbinding it every time you call it, try to avoid this problem in the first place by adjusting the position of your bind command so it executes only once (if there is a way to do so).

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thanks! One part of my page is a frame that is loaded by ajax requests. Each time i fired the keyevents this frame was reloaded and the event listeners stacked. I wrote a new function that combined all of my keyevents (with `on()`) outside of my main javascript and it worked.